# A peculiar decomposition of elements in a group

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be an abelian group. Suppose there exists $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall x\in G, x^n=e$. Let $a,b \in \mathbb N$ such $ab=n$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$.
>
> Let $G_a=\{x^a \; | x\in G\}$ and  $G_b=\{x^b \; | x\in G\}$
>
> 1. Prove that for every $x\in G$, there is a unique $(u,v)\in G_a\times G_b$ such that $x=uv$.
> 2. Assuming $n$ is odd, let $\phi_2:x\to x^2$. Prove that $\phi_2$ is a one-to-one group homomorphism
> 3. Generalize that to $\phi_k$ where $k$ and $n$ are coprime integers.

This problem has been giving me a great deal of trouble.

1. For the existence part, since $a$ and $b$ are coprime there exists $k,l\in \mathbb Z$ such that $ak+bl=1$. Consequently, $x=x^{ak+bl}=(x^k)^a(x^l)^b$.

Regarding uniqueness, since $G_a$ and $G_b$ are subgroups of $G$ it boils down to proving the following lemma:

- If $z\in G_a\cap G_b$ then $z=e$

I feel I'm missing some trick in order to prove this.

2. I attempted to prove injectivity of $\phi_2$, but again, I'm clueless.

I'm mostly looking for hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the following:

> If $x \in G$, then $x^n=1$ if and only if the order of $x$ divides $n$.

In particular this implies that

> If $x \in G$ and $x^a=x^b=1$, then $x^{\gcd(a,b)}=1$.

Now, for (1), take $z=x^a=y^b \in G_a \cap G_b$. Then $y^{b^2}=x^{ab}=x^n=1$, and $y^n=1$. So $z=y^b=y^{\gcd(n,b^2)}=1$.

For (2), the same trick applies. Let $x \in \ker (\phi )$. Then $x^2=1$ and $x^n =1$. So $1= x^{\gcd(2,n)}=x^1=x$. So the kernel is trivial, i.e. $\phi$ is injective.

For (3), you can see that the argument is exactly the same.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this lemma, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

For (1) uniqueness, if $x^a = y^b$ then $x^{a^2} = y^{ab} = 1$.  Also by hypothesis, $x^{ab} = 1$.  Therefore $x^{\gcd(a^2,ab)} = 1$.  And we know that $\gcd(a^2,ab) = a \cdot \gcd(a,b) = a$.  Thus $x^a = 1$.  Similarly $y^b = 1$.